# Google Sheets - script to clear contents on isolated sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

IM trying to get a clearcontent function to work on different tabs. Ive tried several things.

here is exactly what I want to achieve.

clear all content on defined cells within a specific tab. I want this function to work on more than 1 tab but only want the content cleared from 1 tab not all.

attempt #1.

> function ClearCells() {  var sheet =
> SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('tester');
> sheet.getRangeList(['A6:B21' , 'D6:e13']).clearContent();}

I attached this script to a button and it works as it should but only for the specific tab named "tester". I want it to work on a variety of different pages i.e tester, tester 2, tester 3, etc

I also tried this method.

Attempt #2

> function onOpen() {
> var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
> var menubuttons = [ {name: "Clear Sheet", functionName: "clear"},]
> ss.addMenu("Clear Sheet", (menubuttons)) ; }  function clear() {    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('tester');
> sheet.getRange('A6:a21').clearContent(); }

This method works however it only works for 1 tab.

Attempts #3

> function onOpen() {   SpreadsheetApp.getUi()   .createMenu('Reset
> sheet')   .addItem('clearAll', 'clear')   .addToUi(); }
>
> function clear() {
> [{
> sheetName: "tester",
> range: "A5:A30"
> }, {
> sheetName: "tester2",
> range: "A5:A30"
> }].map(obj => clearTable(obj)) }
>
> function clearTable(obj) {
> SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(obj.sheetName).getRange(obj.range)
> .clearContent(); }

Ideally, id like to put  a button on each tab and that button would reset the content on a defined rangelist on that specific tab only

Comment: from your attempt#1 why not create multiple variable to define all the sheets (var sheet1, var sheet2, var sheet3) then clear content?

Answer (score 0):

From `Ideally, id like to put a button on each tab and that button would reset the content on a defined rangelist on that specific tab only`,

In this case, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```js
function ClearCells() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRangeList(['A6:B21', 'D6:E13']).clearContent();
}
```

- In this modified script, when you assign "ClearCells" to the button on each tab and click the button, the sheet with the button is used. And, the ranges are always `'A6:B21', 'D6:E13'` on each sheet.
- For example, if you want to `clearContent()` to the specific sheets by running a script, you can also use the following script. In this script, the sheets of `tester, tester 2, tester 3,,,` are used.

  ```
    function ClearCells2() {
      var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
      sheets.forEach(sheet => {
        if (/^tester/.test(sheet.getSheetName())) {
          sheet.getRangeList(['A6:B21', 'D6:E13']).clearContent();
        }
      });
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [getActiveSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivesheet)
- [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)