# Why does my cell formating not work after replacing the value in the cells with app sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, format

I have a button that replaces various cells (with different numbers ie. 110,15 / 112,00 / 215,75) with "xx" at the end of the day to clear the sheet. There is a custom format set to all these cells "0,00" so that it gives me 2 decimal places. This works fine on the day I set the custom format, however after clearing it upon entering a value (ie. 112) and pressing enter it puts "112" without the decimal places eventhough it should be 112,00. On the format tab it still shows the check mark on the custom format so why doesn't it give the decimal places? Any answer or tips are appreciated!

Example:

I have set the custom format to Cell A1 in which I put 110. After pressing Enter I can see 110,00 in the cell. After the day I clear my sheet with the button and A1 is now "xx". The next morning, I get new data and I enter 112 in the cell. Upon pressing Enter however, the cell shows "112" and not "112,00".

Code: (The code is heavily based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72809160/google-sheets-script-to-clear-contents-on-isolated-sheets) post, credits to the author)

```
   function replaceXX(obj) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(obj.sheetName);
  obj.ranges.map(function(val){
    sheet.getRange(val).setValue("xx");
  });
}
```

the ranges look something like this:

```
   {
      sheetName: "test",
      ranges: ["D5:D7", 'D9', "F5:F7", 'F9', "H5:H7", 'H9', "J5:J9", "L5:L9", "N5:N9", 'P5', 'R5', 'T5']
    },
```

Comment: Please do read [ask] and [edit] your question.

Comment: share your script